# Transpose JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Please help me to do this in javascript.

***this***

```
[{count: 5373, monthname: "November"}]
```

***to this :***

```
[{November: 5373}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using the `map` function as follows

```js
const array = [{ count: 5373, monthname: "November" }];

const result = array.map(item => {
  return { [item.monthname]: item.count };
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
const array = [{ count: 5373, monthname: "November" }];
    
const result = array.map(({monthname, count}) => ({ [monthname]: count }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no restriction on method to solve this then you can do the below:

```
const array = [{count: 5373, monthname: "November"}];
const finalArray = [];

const key = array[0]['monthname'];
const data = array[0]['count'];

finalArray.push({ key: data});
```

The 'finalArray' is your desired array. further if you want to stringify it then use

```
const jsonArray = JSON.stringify(finalArray);
```